# How to create a newcommand for fontsize?

Tags: fonts, macros, fontsize

I am trying to create a command to modify fontsize with one parameter, it seems that the paramater is not expanding properly:

```
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{1.2*#1pt}}
```

Comment: Note that the normal size macros store themselves as `\@currsize`. Most likely so they can be restored. This is not the case in your code or the one is the answers. However, I can't tell you if and what impact this has.

Answer (score 9):

Omit the * if you use a factor. Further, introduce a length macro that can be multiplied. If needed, add `\selectfont` to make it effective:

```
\newlength{\mysize}
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{\setlength{\mysize}{#1pt}%
  \fontsize{\mysize}{1.2\mysize}\selectfont}
```

Comment: Does that work with literal sizes? For example, if I put `\mycfs{10}` won't I get a 1.21 pt baseline separation?

Comment: that's what I think as well.

Comment: Good point, Joseph! I've edited it using a length macro.

Comment: There's even a neat trick that the LaTeX kernel does that allows you to have default units that can be overridden. `\@defaultunits\mysize#1pt\relax\@nnil` I suspect that `\@defaultunits\setlength\mysize{#1pt}\@nnil` would work, but probably not with the `calc` package.

The upshot of this is you can use `\mycfs{.5in}` (or whatever), if you really want.

Comment: @user942, depending on the effect you want, you might try `\fontsize{\mysize}{\f@baselineskip}` in place of `\fontsize{\mysize}{1.2\mysize}` (wrapped between `\makeatother` .. `\makeatletter`, of course). If using LaTeX's internal `\f@baselineskip` gives you what your want (it mightn't do), then you can dispense with the `\mysize` length entirely as well as all the paraphernalia code.

Comment: How do you call this?

Answer (score 7):

This works, using e-TeX functionality to calculate the baseline skip on the fly:

```
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{\dimexpr 1.2pt*#1pt\relax}}
```

Or this solution, without e-TeX, that uses an intermediate dimension register 
so is a bit more complex:

```
\newdimen\mycfsdim
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{\mycfsdim=#1pt \mycfsdim=1.2\mycfsdim 
                       \fontsize{#1pt}{\the\mycfsdim}\selectfont}
```

Comment: I have to say my reaction would be 'use e-TeX', but of course if your sending to a publisher they may not have the extensions!

Answer (score 7):

First of all: In general it is not recommend to freely adjust the font size. Also you of course need a scalable font, otherwise the next fitting one will be chosen.

The used `1.2*#1pt` doesn't work in general. You can use `1.2\somedimension` to get the multiplication.

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{%
  \setlength{\mylength}{#1pt}%
  \setlength{\mylength}{1.2\mylength}%
  \fontsize{#1}{\mylength}%
  \selectfont
}
\makeatother
```

However, some but not all font size macros (`\normalsize`, `\small` and `\footnotesize`) also change other settings like `\abovedisplayskip`, `\belowdisplayskip`, `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`.
To get consistent behavior to would be better to switch to a know font size before you change to yours, e.g. add `\normalsize` at the front of your macro code. You could also adjust the above parameters by yourself, if you know how to do it; correctly I mean.

All font size macros also store themselves into `\@currsize` , e.g. `\small` includes `\let\@currsize\small`, but only if `\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect`. This is done by calling `\@setfontsize` which isn't usable in your case. However, this could be added manually:

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{%
  \normalsize
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
     \def\@currsize{\mycfs{#1}}%
  \fi
  \setlength{\mylength}{#1pt}%
  \setlength{\mylength}{1.2\mylength}%
  \fontsize{#1}{\mylength}%
  \selectfont
}
\makeatother
```

You can further improve this by allowing the input to be a number in pt or any lengths using LaTeX's `\@defaultunits` (as it is done by `\fontsize` itself):

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{%
  \normalsize
  \@defaultunits\mylength=#1pt\relax\@nnil
  \edef\@tempa{{\strip@pt\mylength}}%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
     \edef\@currsize{\noexpand\mycfs\@tempa}% store calculated size
  \fi
  \mylength=1.2\mylength
  \edef\@tempa{\@tempa{\strip@pt\mylength}}%
  \@tempa
  \expandafter\fontsize\@tempa
  \selectfont
}
\makeatother
```