# Changing fontsize within soul underline

Tags: macros, fontsize, soul

This question is related to [How to create a newcommand for fontsize?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/how-to-create-a-newcommand-for-fontsize).
I would like to change the fontsize within `\ul` of the `soul` package. For example:

```
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{1.2#1pt}\selectfont} 
\soulregister{\mycfs}{1}

\ul{{\mycfs{6} Size 6 font} Normal size font}
```

This error message occurs: `! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Have a look at the correction and additional answers to the other topic.

Answer (score 4):

I would change the definition of \mycfs so that it no longer has an argument:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand\mycfs{\fontsize{\mysize}{\the\dimexpr \mysize*1.2\relax}\selectfont}
\newcommand\mysetsize[1]{\edef\mysize{#1pt}}
\soulregister{\mycfs}{0}

\begin{document}
\mysetsize{6}

\ul{\mycfs Size 6 font} Normal size font
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\mbox` could already fix it for you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\newlength{\mysize}
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{\setlength{\mysize}{#1pt}%
  \fontsize{\mysize}{1.2\mysize}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
text

\ul{\mbox{\mycfs{6}Size 6 font} Normal size font}

text
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The trouble with mbox is that is will not line break properly and out out of the margin.

Comment: What is the goal? Underlining long passages or several lines seems strange to me.

Comment: underlining urls

Comment: As underlining is typographically questionable style it's rarely used in texts, even modern webpages try to avoid that. It's a relic of the time of early browsers. So, it's not well supported. Perhaps have a look at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=underline - maybe you might find a better emphasizing of URLs than underlining? Bold, colored, or typewriter font?