# \@setfontsize vs. \fontsize

Tags: fontsize

What are the differences between    `\@setfontsize` and    `\fontsize`?

For example, in Martin Scharrer's answer to [How to create a newcommand for fontsize?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/how-to-create-a-newcommand-for-fontsize/22201#22201) he says:

> This is done by calling `\@setfontsize` which isn't usable in your case.

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command `\@setfontsize` has a `@` in its name, which means it's a "low level" or, perhaps better, internal command. It shouldn't appear in a normal document apart perhaps in the preamble to make some particular definition.

The definition of `\fontsize` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\fontsize}[2]{%
  \set@fontsize \baselinestretch {#1}{#2}}
```

which means that the user level command `\fontsize` hands control to `\set@fontsize`. This is a common technique in LaTeX.

The internal command `\@setfontsize` has a different purpose from `\fontsize`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 3611:
\def\@setfontsize#1#2#3{\@nomath#1%
    \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
      \let\@currsize#1%
    \fi
    \fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont}
```

It's typically found in "class option files" such as `size10.clo`, for instance

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

Let's see what happens when `\normalsize` is called (most of the times implicitly); LaTeX does

```
\@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
```

that, in view of the definition above, becomes

```
\@nomath\normalsize
\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\let\@currsize\normalsize\fi
\fontsize{\@xpt}{\@xiipt}\selectfont
```

The first line `\normalsize` tells LaTeX to disallow `\normalsize` in math mode; the second line sets `\@currsize` to be equivalent to `\normalsize`, but only during normal typesetting (it does nothing, for instance, in write operations). Finally the command `\fontsize` is called with font size 10pt and baselineskip 12pt, then the font is actually selected.

Thus you see that `\@setfontsize` is an internal utility and calling it in a document doesn't make sense.

What's the purpose of `size10.clo`? Classes such as `article` and `report` are usually written in a "size independent" way; a size option (that may be the default one) causes LaTeX to read `size10.clo`, `size11.clo` or `size12.clo` (it's `bk10.clo`, `bk11.clo` or `bk12.clo` for the `book` class). These files set up the font selections and the parameters for lists and many other things that depend on the main body font size.

Comment: Thank you for helpful insight.  So     \@setfontsize do the same thing as  \fontsize plus actualize \@currsize.     In my opinion every macro which change font size should actualize  \@currsize. So I think using  \@setfontsize is better.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterSarvas That's what `\large`, `\small` and the other commands do, since they are defined in a similar way to `\normalsize`

Comment: So when I want define custom macro like \large, \small (e.g. \mysize) should I use \@setfontsize?

Comment: @PeterSarvas It's better, indeed.

Comment: It brings us to my second question. Martin Scharrer in his answer (link above) says, that he can't use \@setfontsize. Why?

Comment: @PeterSarvas I really don't know.