# Creating a custom font size

Tags: fonts, fontsize

In [this query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/how-to-create-a-newcommand-for-fontsize), @MartinSharrer provides a nice macro to create a custom fontsize.      Unfortunately, I don't understand how to use it.

The code below uses his macro

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newlength{\mylength}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycfs}[1]{%
  \normalsize
  \@defaultunits\mylength=#1pt\relax\@nnil
  \edef\@tempa{{\strip@pt\mylength}}%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
     \edef\@currsize{\noexpand\mycfs\@tempa}% store calculated size
  \fi
  \mylength=1.2\mylength
  \edef\@tempa{\@tempa{\strip@pt\mylength}}%
  \@tempa
  \expandafter\fontsize\@tempa
  \selectfont
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\mycfs{8} This is a test} \\
{\mycfs{7} This is a test} \\
{\mycfs{6} This is a test} \\
{\mycfs{5} This is a test} \\
\end{document}
```

But produces this output [image].

The font selection part is great but I can't figure out how to remove the numbers at the beginning of each line. Could somebody advise please?

Comment: Why can't you just use `\fontsize` ? (as in flav's answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to remove the numbers at the beginning of each line.

Simply remove the line that contains just `\@tempa`.

Answer (score 25):

using fontsize and selectfont (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

Coucou

\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont
Coucou

\fontsize{28pt}{28pt}\selectfont
Coucou

\end{document}
```

[image]